# How can I count each unique string / observation for a variable, without manually specifying a string?

Tags: r, count, pipe, unique, tidyverse

So I have some data that looks like this:

[image]

from running the following:

```
unique_names <- naming_data %>% 
  gather(stimuli, names) %>%            # Change from wide to long format. 
  group_by(stimuli) %>%                 # Set image name as grouping variable. 
  arrange (stimuli, names) %>%          # Sort by stimuli, then by names. 
  na.omit() %>%                         # Drop NA rows. 
  filter(!str_detect(names, 'no'))      # Drop rows with 'no' responses.
```

I'm trying to find out how many unique 'names' each 'stimuli' has, but a simple count of the unique items like this **does not** give me all of the information I need:

```
stimuli                unique

anchor1_photo_colour   3
apple2_photo_grey      4
```

Instead, I need something that lists all of the unique 'names' given for each 'stimuli' (this number will differ for each 'stimuli' - e.g. some might only have 1 name, others might have 5). I then want to count the occurrences of each one, so I can calculate proportions and see which of the given 'names' was the most frequent. I'm looking for an output similar to this:

```
stimuli                names     count

anchor1_photo_colour   anchor    17
anchor1_photo_colour   pickaxe   1
anchor1_photo_colour   shovel    1
apple2_photo_grey      apple     16
apple2_photo_grey      peach     2
apple2_photo_grey      fruit     1
apple2_photo_grey      a         1
```

I can then determine that, for anchor1_photo_colour, "anchor" was the most common name (17 - 89.4%), but there was not complete agreement for this name. I have ~800 different 'stimuli', each of which have ~20 'names'. The only solutions I've found require manually specifying the string you want to count, but with ~800 stimuli (and multiple names given for each one), this is not possible. That would also involve manually 'looking' at the data, and leaves room for error (i.e. I might incorrectly state that some stimuli have 100% agreement, when in fact there was a different name given that I just happened to miss when eyeballing the data).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `library(data.table); setDT(data)[, .(count = .N), by = .(stimuli, names)]`

Comment: How about `naming_data %>% count(stimuli, names)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
unique_names %>% count(names,stimuli)
```

Comment: Well that was deceptively easy! I just need to delete the duplicate rows, but then I have the exact output I was looking for. Many thanks - I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: Note I replaced my solution, once I realized you don't need to keep all the rows. This will remove the duplicates automatically.

Comment: Even better! I just added '''distinct()''' under it, but even that's not needed with "count". Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `table` from `base R`

```
as.data.frame(table(unique_names[c('names', 'stimuli')]))
```